# Flutter 'GlobalKey' don't know how to fix, when opened window -> this error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication

Good day, when I run flutter -> errors in the window like 'GlobalKey was used multiple times inside one widget's child list..' Sorry if it is a stupid question.. so what do I have to do?

HOW do I understand I used 'global key' more than 1times -> what should I do?

code ->

```
Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Mama',
      onGenerateRoute: (settings){
        switch(settings.name){
          case '/home':
            return PageTransition(
              child: HomePage(),
              type: PageTransitionType.fade
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = new GlobalKey();

  processLogin(BuildContext context) async{
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if(user == null){
      FirebaseAuthUi.instance()
        .launchAuth([AuthProvider.phone()]).then((FirebaseUser) async {
          context.read().state = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

          // Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          //   context, '/home', (route) => false);
          await checkLoginState(context,true);
            
           ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Login Success ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.phoneNumber}')));

        }).catchError((e){
          if(e is PlatformException)
            if(e.code == FirebaseAuthUi.kUserCancelledError){
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('${e.message}')));
            }
            else{
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Unk Error')));
            }
        });
    }
    else{

    }
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context, watch){
      return  Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldState,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/my_bg.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children:[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child:FutureBuilder(
                future: checkLoginState(context,false),
                builder: (context, snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else{
                    var userState = snapshot.data as LOGIN_STATE;
                    if(userState == LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED){
                      return Container();
                    }
                    else{
                      return ElevatedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: ()=> processLogin(context),
                        icon :Icon(Icons.phone, color: Colors.white,),
                        label: Text('LOGIN WITH ME', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white),),
                        style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                        );
                    }
                  }
                }
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  
  }
  
  Future<LOGIN_STATE> checkLoginState(BuildContext context, bool fromLogin) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: fromLogin == true ? 0 : 3)).then((value)=>{
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
        ?.getIdToken()
        .then((token){
          print('$token');
          context.read().state = token;
          Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, '/home', (route) => false);

        })
    });

    return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null 
      ? LOGIN_STATE.LOGGED
      : LOGIN_STATE.NOT_LOGIN;

  }

}
```

QUESTION:
How do I properly use Globalkeys to ensure that there is only one per widget? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Nothing, Expecting an answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to store global key inside a variable then use the variable name wherever you want to use, take reference from the below code, I am not sure, whether it will help you or not, but you will get an idea from this.

```
      final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
       child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Invalid email!';
                    }
                    return null;
                    // return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['email'] = value!;
                  },
                ),
),
```

> also , you have written three lines like this,
> ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext!).
> here,replace "scaffoldState" with context.